# Problems in installing the latest edition of Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I am trying to install Texmaker 4.1 on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I downloaded the file from the  official site and I am trying to install by using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.1_i386.deb
```

However, this results in an error of whose origin I am unable to pinpoint. The error message is as follows:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.1_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package texmaker.
(Reading database ... 617874 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking texmaker (from texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmaker/doc14hu.png', which is also in package texmaker-data 3.4-1~ubuntu12.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.1_i386.deb
```

What can I do to remedy the situation? Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't simply install it from the deb package as I suggested before? I think your ubuntu installation has a problem.

Comment: Yeah just like you mentioned I tried to install it by double clicking the .deb package when it failed, I considered trying the command line. By the way I am done with the TexStudio it works really well for now.

Comment: I used the following command and it took care of the problem. However, lot of overwriting operations were performed as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Mmm I think it is related with your own installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 64-bit, Texmaker 4.3:

```
sudo dpkg --install texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.3_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 382851 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking texmaker (from texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.3_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmaker/usermanual_fr.html', which is also in package texmaker-data 3.2-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.3_amd64.deb
```

I forced the over write as follows...
`sudo dpkg --install --force-overwrite texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.3_amd64.deb`

Comment: Your solution still works on ubuntu 15.10 with texmaker 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to install TeXmaker using deb package with the following command.

```
sudo dpkg --install --force-overwrite texmaker_5.0.2_ubuntu_17_10_amd64.deb
```

Comment: The OP is running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Will this work?